# How to create QList from std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, containers, stdvector, qlist

[`QList::fromStdList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#fromStdList) allows you to create `QList` from `std::list`. But how to create `QList` from `std::vector`?

Of course, **aside from manual looping**:

```
QList<T> myList;
myList.reserve(vector.size());
for(size_t i = 0, l = vector.size(); i < l; ++i)
    myList << vector[i];
```

Comment: Wow, never realized they did not have iterator range constructors.  That is a surprising lack of functionality.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I am equally just realizing so... I checked their other containers... Astonishingly ridiculous

Comment: Now they have iterator constructors. U can use like QList<T>::fromVector(QVector<T>(vec.begin(), vec.end()))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

QVector can be created from a std vector, so you could do this if you want to avoid a loop:

```
QList<T> myList = QList<T>::fromVector(QVector<T>::fromStdVector(vector));
```

Of course, this would create an unnecessary copy in the process. Instead of having to write a loop, you could also use a std::copy and back_inserter

```
QList<T> myList;
myList.reserve(vector.size());
std::copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::back_inserter(myList));
```

Comment: Interestingly, `QList::reserve` takes an `int`, while `std::vector.size` returns an unsigned integral type. Depending on your compiler settings you may get a 'conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data' warning/error.

Comment: Note: from Qt's documentation: the generic container classes should be used instead, as stated in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#fromStdVector and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html.